# Permeability constant in Ampère's circuital law must be vacuum permeability $\mu_0$?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Just to be sure, is the permeability constant in Ampère's circuital law always equal to $\mu_0$, regardless of which medium the Amperian loop is placed in? That is, $\oint {\bf B} \cdot d {\bf \ell} = \mu_0 I$ and never equal to $\mu I$.

My reasoning is that if $\mu \neq \mu_0$, then using Stoke's theorem,
\begin{align*}
\oint {\bf B} \cdot d {\bf \ell} &= \mu I \\
\int (\nabla \times {\bf B}) \cdot d{\bf S} &= \mu \int {\bf J \cdot} d{\bf S} \\
\nabla \times {\bf B} &= \mu {\bf J}  \\
&= \mu ({\bf J}_f + {\bf J}_b)\\
&= \mu (\nabla \times {\bf H} + \nabla \times {\bf M}) \\
&= \mu [ \nabla \times ({\bf H} + {\bf M}) ] \\
{\bf B} &= \mu({\bf H} + {\bf M})
\end{align*}
But this contradicts with ${\bf B} = \mu_0({\bf H} + {\bf M})$.

*Therefore, the $\mu$ must be equal to $\mu_0$.*

**Corollary**:
Some books define Ampère's circuital law as $\oint {\bf H} \cdot d {\bf \ell} = I$. This is true if we are dealing with ${\bf B}$ in free space (or if $I=I_f$, see comment below). That is, we place the Amperian loop in free space such that 
\begin{align*}
\oint {\bf B} \cdot d {\bf \ell} &= \mu_0 I\\
\oint \frac{\bf B}{\mu_0} \cdot d{\bf \ell}&= I \\
\oint {\bf H}\cdot d{\bf \ell}&= I
\end{align*}
If ${\bf B}$ is not in free space then $\frac{\bf B}{\mu_0} \neq {\bf H}$ and thus $\oint {\bf H}\cdot d{\bf \ell} \neq I$ (unless $I=I_f$, see comment below).

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: @DvijMankad Because never have I seen any source defining $\oint {\bf B} \cdot d {\bf \ell} = \mu I$. It seems like the $\mu$ must be equal to $\mu_0$ in order for the law to work.

Comment: $\oint {\bf H} \cdot d {\bf \ell} = I_{free}$.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Yes, thanks for mentioning. $\nabla \times {\bf H} = {\bf J_f}$, $I_f = \int {\bf J}_f \cdot d{\bf S} = \int \nabla \times {\bf H} \cdot d{\bf S} = \oint {\bf H} \cdot d {\bf \ell} $.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one of the correct forms of the law is $\oint {\bf B} \cdot d {\bf \ell} = \mu_0 I $, (not$ \mu$)and $I$ is all the currents included in the loop (free current in conductors, bound current due to spins, current due to orbital motion of electrons, everything).

Inside a linear medium (with permeability being constant inside it), one can use the formula $\oint {\bf B} \cdot d {\bf \ell} = \mu I_{free}$, where $ \mu = \mu_r \mu_0$, but this may not work if the loop of integration passes through multiple mediums.

Note that the above can be derived from  $\oint {\bf H} \cdot d {\bf \ell} = I_{free}$ (in your question you have written $I$, but it should be $I_{free}$, then everything fits together and it is valid in any medium), which is another form of Ampere's law. In this form only free currents are included.

Comment: How would one proceed if the loop of integration passes through multiple mediums? For an example visit my question which got marked as "duplicate".

Comment: @ludz The two equations will remain as is. For $\oint {\bf B} \cdot d {\bf \ell} = \mu_0 I$, one needs to consider all currents including currents in the medium. For linear mediums, $\mu I_{free} = \mu_0 I_{total}$. The other equation $\oint {\bf H} \cdot d {\bf \ell} = I_{free}$ is for free currents, and will remain the same.

Comment: @ludz It is always $\mu_0$, but you need to consider the total current (there can be bound currents in a medium, and you need to consider them also).

Comment: If I understood you correctly then the equation for my example with two wires with different magnetic permeability is still $\oint \vec B \cdot \vec{dl}=\mu_0 I_{tot}$ but $I_{tot}$ is not necessarily equal to $2I$? $I_{tot}=free current + bound current$?

Comment: @ludz Yes, you got it right, We get free current when those free charges move. Bound currents are the circulating currents at the boundaries which give rise to permanent magnetic moments (usually they are due to spin of electrons). See https://courses.physics.illinois.edu/phys435/sp2014/p435web/magnetization.pdf for some diagrams.

Comment: Okay thank you! Much appreciated for taking your time to answer even though this question was asked 2 years ago.