Permeability in equation of field due to ideal solenoid
The magnetic field well inside a long solenoid is given by $\mu_0 n i$, where $n$ is the number of turns per unit length and $i$ is current flowing in the tightly wound wire.
However, I'm confused what this $\mu_0$ is. I understand that it is the permeability of free space and that we can also write $\mu_0 \mu_r$ for a non vacuum medium.
$\mu_r$ is relative permeability of that medium.
However, I am trying to understand whether we write the permeability in the equation of the surrounding of the rod or of the rod itself on which the wire is wound?
I'm asking this because while deriving the equation using Ampere's Circuital Law, we take a loop which is outside and inside the solenoid body (some part is out and some is inside).
Any help is appreciated.

Did you see this discussion?   If you include relative mu from a different material, then you also have to consider "bound currents".
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/480976/permeability-constant-in-amp%c3%a8res-circuital-law-must-be-vacuum-permeability-mu?rq=1

Deriving Solenoid Equation - Amperean loop
Let us take the following Amperean loop:
A rectangle, with leg 1 vertical and within the solenoid, leg 2 horizontal going from within to outside the solenoid, leg 3 vertical outside the solenoid, and leg 4 horizontal and going into the solenoid.
I am going to take your 'very long solenoid' as an 'ideal solenoid', one which is infinitely long (or can be approximated to be so)
Let us take a circulation direction that is clockwise.
Ampere's law states that $\oint B\cdot dl = \mu_0 I_{enclosed}$. The closed loop integral is saying that you do the sum around a closed loop.
In our Amperean loop, legs 2 and 4 have $B\cdot dl=0$ as the displacement vector along these horizontal legs and the magnetic field (which is vertical) are perpendicular, hence their dot products are zero.
Interlude on Solenoid Explanation - Magnetic Field outside
For the vertical leg 3, which is outside the solenoid, $B\cdot dl=0$ as well, but for a much more finicky reason. To prove this, let us go to infinity away from the solenoid. The magnetic field is 0 there, so $B\cdot dl=0$ for that vertical leg. Now take a very large Amperean rectangle, with one leg on leg 3, the other vertical leg at infinity, and the horizontal legs connecting these.
Since there is no current enclosed here, and the vertical leg at infinity, as well as horizontal legs have $B\cdot dl=0$ for the same reason as above. So, for Ampere's law to be true, the last leg must have $B\cdot dl=0$ as well, so that the closed loop is equal to $0$.
Using the original Amperean loop, we can calculate both the magnetic field outside and inside now. Now we know only leg 1 contributes to $\oint B\cdot dl$, wherein $\mu_0 I_{enc} = \mu_0 ni$ by your definition of $n$ and $i$, thus proving that magnetic field inside is $\mu_0 ni$
This 'proof' was a bit tongue-in-cheek, check out MIT OCW 8.02 for a comprehensive explanation, the infinite solenoid is in Week 9 I believe.
Further explanation, Intuitiveness and Permeability of Free Space
Here are the assumptions hidden within this proof, as well as an explanation to what $\mu_0$ actually represents

The fact that the magnetic field is vertical

This can be explained using the right hand rule, but also symmetry. Since at any point in the solenoid (which we've approximated as infinitely long) there is an equal 'amount' of current above and below, there shouldn't be any horizontal magnetic fields. Extending further, if there were horizontal magnetic fields, it would allow us to break the vertical symmetry.

What is the free permeability of free space doing here?

This constant is a value, a measure of how much resistance a magnetic field encounters in a vacuum. As Daniil Zhitov wrote well in his answer, the relative permeability is necessary for different media. In our case, in the equation $B_in = \mu_0 nI$, the value is a scaling factor between current enclosed and the magnetic field. If it were different, with the same current in a vacuum, a different magnetic field would be produced.
So, to actually answer the question, $\mu_0$ is a measure of how strong a magnetic field is in a vacuum, and the permeability is a factor in every equation of a magnetic field that is derived from Ampere's Law. In the case of an ideal solenoid, which is what I assume that your teacher was getting at, there is no magnetic field outside, and the permeability is in the equation within the solenoid (I think that's what you meant by 'rod').
Hope this was helpful!

The Ampere's law can be formulated in two equivalent ways:
$$
\oint B \cdot dl = \mu_0 I_{total},
$$
$$
\oint H \cdot dl = \mu_0 I_{free}.
$$
The difference between the two expressions comes from magnetization currents. In the scenario that you describe, free currents are the currents flowing in the wires.
Normally, when deriving field of a long solenoid, the main contribution to the contour integral comes from the region inside. In that region $B=\mu_r\mu_0H$ where $\mu_r$ is the relative permeability of the medium. It is $\mu_r$ of the medium and not the wire, since we are relating B,H on the integration contour deep inside the solenoid.
Therefore, we obtain
$$
H_{in} L = \mu_0 I N \Rightarrow H_{in}=\mu_0 n I
$$
and
$$
B_{in} = \mu_r\mu_0 n I.
$$
The outside part of the contour is irrelevant since there $B=\mu_0 H\approx 0$.
